# Responsive Image - how to?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

In Android XML's I have my images as such:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/cl_movie_poster"
            android:layout_width="41dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="41:63"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/gl_left_gutter"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/gl_top_gutter">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/movie_poster"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/lbl_poster_image"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:nullableImageUrl="http://www.example.com/image.png"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                />

            <ImageView
                style="@style/MoviePosterDecorator"
                android:id="@+id/movie_image_decorator"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/decorator_dow_friday"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But my image does not adjust sizes as the screen changes. How can I set the image to adjust sizes and keep the same ratio as the layout changes?

Answer (score 0):

add this to your imageview

```
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

and set your

```
layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: and set your layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: You can edit your answer, instead of adding a comment to it.

Comment: No, wrap_content makes it disappear